# MongoDB connection overhead on client side

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant

We are evaluating different alternatives for multi-tenancy in our platform. We think that one database per customer is the way to go as data structure and requirements are completely different from one customer to another, and we want to keep them as isolated as possible.

However we are facing the question of how to manage the connection to multiple databases. We don't want to have one app instance per customer. Instead we want to have a pool of app instances handling requests for all our customers and use the correct database depending on the customer.

Our concern is if keeping connections open to many (maybe thousands) of database will cause a performance issue. We are actually worried about memory usage, so we are wondering what's the overhead on client side when performing a connection to the MongoDB server.

Also we are thinking about moving the database access to a different service, which is going to be responsible of handling the database connection for all customers. In this case, is there an existing tool that allows to do that kind of "multiplexing" of MongoDB databases?

Some additional notes:

- We discarded sharding. It won't fit our needs. We need different databases.
- Databases will be in different servers with reserved resources. This means all databases run its own mondod process and we need different connections.
- We use Java driver.

Comment: Errr.. you're using separate database *instances* for client isolation? I find that rather uncommon and somewhat extreme... If you do that, you should also create different app instances IMHO. In any case, we need to know *which* client you're using. Generally speaking, many drivers create a connection pool for each database instance they're connected to, and you'll probably not need that many parallel connections to a single database. Also, socket overhead might depend on the OS as well, and the total number of open sockets is strictly limited by the OS...

Comment: Yes, we are using separate database instances. We want to make sure that one customer doesn't affect other customers without restricting them about what they do with the database.

We are using the Java driver which configures a connection pool. We deploy on Linux.